# play local mp4 file in xamarin.forms web view for mac?

Tags: macos, xamarin.forms, html5-video

I'm beginner to Xamarin.Forms, by using it we are developing a mac application. One of my requirement is to play local mp4 video file.

We did some R&D on video players which can play videos in mac. We found few plugins like - 
https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager 
, unfortunately none of them work for us in mac. So we decided to try webview.

xaml code -

```
<WebView x:Name="Browser" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
```

xaml.cs code -

```
    string myVideoHtml = String.Format(
            @"<html>
                <body>
                    <video width='100%' height='100%'     
                           autoplay controls>
                        <source src='{0}' type='video/mp4'/>
                    </video>
                </body>
            </html>",
            "movie.mp4");

    var html = new HtmlWebViewSource { Html = myVideoHtml };
    Browser.Source = html;
```

Placed 'movie.mp4' file inside 'Resource' folder and set 'Buid Action' to 'BundleResource'.
I checked in iOS, its playing the video but in macOS video is not playing.

Some of the observations I made as below. Your help is much appreciated, thanks.

- If video is from online source, its playing.
- If I set some html string or website url, it works.